# Benefits of having a `Not-A-Robot` badge

Tags: support, badges, not-a-robot-badge

Recently I heard about this badge called 'Not-A-Robot' which is awarded to the members who participated in Stack Overflow official events.

So, I'm curious about benefits of the [Not-A-Robot](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot) badge. What are they?

Comment: Bragging rights. Nothing else.

Comment: AFAIK, the only badges with side-effects are gold tag-badges for the dupe-hammer, and edit-badges to be able to nominate yourself as a mod during elections.

Comment: The Not-A-Robot badge should be winnable by passing a set of CAPTCHAs. Or can robots solve CAPTCHAs now?

Comment: What's the benefit of badges, in general? Why would this one be any different?

Comment: That would be too easy @RobertColumbia. The badge is meant to get us out of our chairs and go ... *shrug* ... outside ....

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like the kind of question a robot would ask.

Comment: @Jaydles Total robotism, if you ask me :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are none. Badges are meant as encouragement (next to reputation) for participating in the site. Except for gold tag badges, which grant [dupehammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230865/295232) rights, and a handful of badges necessary to nominate yourself as a [Stack Overflow ♦ moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/election/), badges provide no tangible benefit whatsoever.

Comment: We don't need no steenking badges!