# Not A Robot Badge Not Valid - How to get help?

Tags: support, not-a-robot-badge

I got a not a robot sticker at a recent event, but when I got home and put in the code to get the badge, it was expired.

Does anyone know the official channel I could use to ask about fixing this?

Comment: They found you out. Just accept it. We know you are one of them. But we welcome our new cybernetic overlords!

Comment: Admit it, there's a capcha after the code, and you couldn't solve the capcha, could you, robot?!  (seriously though, the official channel is likely here, or through the "contact us" form)

Comment: The paper keeps slipping out of my ~physical manipulator claws~ hands so I can't read the code!

Comment: @Patrice Ah! I didn't see the Contact Us link at the bottom. I'll try that, thank you!

Comment: @ErtySeidohl My pleasure. Please remember I was helpful when you and your co-robots take over the world :) offer me something... or at least a quick death :D

Comment: What's funny is that the not-a-robot tag has a QR code URL and a hex password on it, meaning it's actually easier for robots to read than ~meatbags~ humans...

Comment: I can't tell if you are joking or meant to be serious.  Be sure to [read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364551/benefits-of-having-a-not-a-robot-badge).

Comment: @Hans Joking about being a robot!, serious about the question! I did actually go to an event and get a tag, and it was expired before I could use it!

Comment: I did just realize that I'd worded the question badly. I got a sticker at the event, and I'd like to get the associated badge on stackoverflow. Just for fun of course.

Comment: Yeah, yeah... We are on to you. You won't get us with your [metal claws](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXnL7sdElno).

Comment: Are there events outside of America?

Comment: Next time, make sure that it is not a robot who gives you the sticker...

Comment: @Cœur I wish there was, but it's highly unlikely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reached out via the contact us link (down there vvvvv) and now I have the badge.